# How can I combine regex on django to match like ("string"<var>)?

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I'm trying to make the following url:

```
www.example.com/series/the-walking-dead/season-1/episode-1/
```

And the following url on my urls.py

```
url(r'^series/(?P<se>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/season-(?P<tp>\d+)/episode-(?P<ep>\d+)/$'
    ,EpisodioView),
```

But it is not matching. Is it possible?

Comment: Does Django cut off the host from the URL? If not, remove the `^` from the beginning.

Comment: Django cut it off with no problems. I have other urls working well, I only want this one.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing the `/` before `series`? Depends on the rest of your urls file if that's needed or not, but I think it might be missing. Try and remove the `^` to test :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the error was in the app... The regular expression works fine.

Really sorry guys.

Comment: In this case, just delete the question.